# Programatically edit username password stored in Web.config

Tags: asp.net

I am using forms authentication with username and password stored inside web.config, is there anyway that I can modify web.config programmatically through another aspx file so that my users are able to change their password ?

Comment: username and password stored inside web.config????????

Comment: Web.Config uses an xml-setup. You could read it out from another program and edit its values. But why not use a database?

Comment: @Matthijs I am storing information for a single user only, therefore a database setup is overkill

Comment: @cherhan: That changes your question; "users" turning into "user". Be clear when asking questions! Also, the link LittleBobbyTables provided should help you out.

Comment: For those wondering why am I storing username and password in Web.config, see this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7t6b43z4(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

With the help of 'WebConfigurationManager' class you can easily do it,

see below snippet

```
var szCongigMan = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var connectionstringSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)szCongigMan.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionstringSection.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
szCongigMan.Save();
```

Comment: The samething was added already in a comment by LittleBobbyTables :)